# Thin client FL300 software?

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop, cloud

My cloud computer **FL300** thin-client is wiped , how can i install its operating system again , can any one help me with that , i searched for it on the net but i couldn't find anything , it has embedded Linux 2.6 OS .

Any one has an experince with this device , is it easy to have it work again ?

This is a picture for the device :

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you contact the vendor? "Linux 2.6" is a little vague -- that's just the kernel version.

Comment: i couldnot contact the vendor , i chip it one year ago from china

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my device after i told it to reset to factory defaults.  The hdmi video default setting was the issue.  I hooked mine up to vga and it worked and then i was able to change the video settings back to hdmi.